# Strange require statement errors in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, require

I've got a wrapper for my Gem, socks, inside `socks.rb`. The entire file is made up of require statements, and a module declaration:

```
# lib/socks.rb
require 'socks/version'
require 'socks/base_controller'
require 'socks/templates'
require 'socks/tasks'
require 'socks/rake_tasks'

module Socks
end
```

However, `require 'socks/tasks'` and `socks/rake_tasks` is giving me a `LoadError: no such file to load -- socks/tasks` / `rake_tasks` error.

Is this a problem with the alignment of the require statements, or just the code?

**Code is on Github:** https://github.com/Beakr/socks

**EDIT**: `require './socks/tasks'` is now working, however `require './socks/rake_tasks'` is not.

Comment: In the github project you've linked to (3a2ebd5) there isn't a socks/tasks or socks/rake_tasks file that I can see.

Comment: I haven't yet pushed those changes.

Comment: Try it out with require_relative and point the location to the `socks/tasks` and `socks/rake_tasks`.

Comment: @Kashyap yes, it's a `.rb` file

Comment: @Kashyap `require_relative` is throwing me `LoadError: cannot infer basepath`.

Comment: I've tested it: 
`one.rb`
    puts [1, 2, 3, 4]

`two.rb`
    require_relative 'one.rb'

`ruby two.rb`
prints: 

    1
    2
    3
    4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby load files using its `$LOAD_PATH`. This global array is changed by e.g. rubygems and bundler to allow to find libraries in various locations. In your `sock.gemspec` you have defined

```
gem.require_paths = ["lib"]
```

which means that rubygems will add the `lib` directory of your gem to ruby's `$LOAD_PATH`. But it odes so only if you have installed the gem and the gemspec is thus evaluated. If you don't want to install your gem, you can test your gem using

```
bundle exec irb
```

in your gem directory, or alternatively by first adapting your `$LOAD_PATH` in your irb session like so:

```
$LOAD_PATH.push "/path/to/your/gem/lib"
require 'socks'
```